# GSM Modem show CME ERROR:262 Sim is blocked, but working in Cell Phone

Tags: gsm, at-command

I have been using GSM Modem at work for sending sms notifications for a while. It was working good, however when I tried using it today it gives me `+CME ERROR: 262`. This means: Sim Card is Blocked, I have no idea why.

Previously these commands worked:

```
ATZ
OK
AT+CMEE = 1
OK
AT+CSCS="UCS2" 
OK
AT+CSMP=17,167,0,0
+CME ERROR: 262
AT+CMGF = 0
OK
AT+CMGS = 81
+CME ERROR: 262
```

I have tried other SIM cards, and used GSM 7 encoding, but I still get same error.

UPDATE: I tested this Card on mobile phone, ant it works perfectly, however any SIM I put in GSM modem, is Blocked somehow.

UPDATE: I changed my modem with same model modem, ant it works. Probably some hardware malfunction of this old modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found that was causing this issue.

It seems what SIM card inserted into GSM modem didn't have good **contact**. I changed my modem and now it works like a charm